# Program to automate multiple ID (input)verification in URL and get the status of the ID using webbrowser

Tags: c#, winforms

A program to automate the process of checking a set of UserIds passing as a input to a webform in a url and get the status using webbrowser . for Single Ids its working , but to automate for N number of ids, loop is not working but taking the last id and returns the output .

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = "https://www.verify.xhtml";
    WebBrowser b = new WebBrowser();
    b.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    b.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(b_DocumentCompleted);
    b.Navigate(url);
}

private void b_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        WebBrowser b = sender as WebBrowser;
        b.Document.GetElementById("idnumber").InnerText = idarray[i];
        //string listobj = b.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select")[0].GetElementsByTagName("option")[1].SetAttribute("selected", "selected");
        // string response = b.DocumentText;

        b.Document.GetElementById("frmType1").SetAttribute("value", "24Q");

        HtmlElement btnlink = b.Document.GetElementById("clickGo1");
        btnlink.InvokeMember("Click");
        b.DocumentCompleted -= new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(b_DocumentCompleted);
        b.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(b_result);

    }
    //enter code here
}
```

I am getting the result from the site for the last ID ..how to perform the loop start from the first ID .. Please suggest me some changes in this code to get the code work as expected . thanks

Comment: I would use a web client and post a new form with a different ID value rather than programmatically click around a web browser

Comment: yes this is also working .just i am missing the loop process for mulitple Ids ...